# KNN search, growing set, arbitrary norm

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, metrics, knn

Suppose the following problem in E3 with an arbitrary norm. For example,  L1 norm is used (Hamming, Karlsruhe, geodesic, ..., are also applicable).

```
namespace {
   typedef boost::tuple<double, double, double> Point;

   double nL1(const Point& p1, const Point& p2) {  //L1 norm, example
        double dx = p1.get<0>() - p2.get<0>();
        double dy = p1.get<1>() - p2.get<1>();
        double dz = p1.get<2>() - p2.get<2>();
        return abs(dx) + abs(dy) + abs(dz);
  }
}
```

There are two sets *A*, *B*. *A* is initialized by n random points, where *n* is relatively large (n = 1*10^7 - 1*10^9), *B* is empty; see the sample code:

```
int main() {
   using namespace std;
   using namespace boost::lambda;

   vector<Point> A, B;
   int n = 10000000;
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  //Create random points
      A.push_back(boost::make_tuple(rand(), rand(), rand()));
```

Initially, we put a random point from *A* to *B*. In the simplified example, the first point A[0] is used:

```
   B.push_back(A[0]);
```

Subsequently, for i = 1:n we repeat these steps:

- Find the nearest point in *B* to A[i] according to a given norm

  ```
   B * = argmin(|A[i]-B|)
  ```
- If |B* - A[i]| < eps, then B.push_back(A[i]). In other words, add sufficiently close A[i] to *B* (Here, eps = 1.0*10^4 is used).

For the nearest search, I am using the std::partial_sort.

```
   const int k = 1;
   for (int i = 1; i < A.size(); i++) {
       partial_sort(B.begin(), B.begin() + k, B.end(), bind(less<double>(), bind(nL1, _1, A[i]), bind(nL1, _2, A[i])));
       if (nL1(*B.begin(), A[i]) < 1e4) B.push_back(A[i]); //Some threshold, eps=1.0*10^4 
   }
}
```

*B* is continuously growing and the search becomes more expensive...  Being repeated in the loop, it is too slow, even for small sets (n=1*10^6)... Here, the partial sort is inefficient.

- Are there significant **improvements** in speed? Of course, a naive approach can be used (but it is not faster).
- How to speed up nn-search?

Another problem appears when also the second nearest points is required...

Current k-nn search libraries can not be used because of an arbitrary norm (the problem can be solved on the sphere). I tried to use nano-flann, but it does not support some specific norms...

Comment: What is the Karlsruhe norm? With geodesic, are you talking about some surface in E3? Anyway, you should still be able to use a kd-tree, you just need to be able to answer certain questions like: is this ball (for your norm) included in this box?